# Google visualization map not rendering

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-visualization

I am trying to load locations from a json in to a Google Charts map using latitude, longitude and name. I have created other Google Charts and they are working fine but the map just wont render for me. I have a Google maps Api key on the html file and also call the javascript and php files from here. I've been looking at this for days now but cant seem to see whys its failing, can a fresh pair of eyes see whats going wrong? Thanks in advance.

The php file pulling a query from the database and sending it to the json;

```
    <?php

include '..\..\include\demo_conn.php'; 


    $conn = new PDO($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS); 

    $result = $conn->prepare('SELECT lat as "Lat",
                                lon as "Long",
                                name as "Name"
                                FROM locations');

    $result->execute(); 

 $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.


    array('label' => 'Lat', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Long', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Name', 'type' => 'string')

);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {

      $temp = array();

      // Trailer codes

      $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r['Lat']); 

      // Values of the each location

      $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r['Long']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Name']);
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

//write to json file
    $fp = fopen('demo_02.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($table));
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

This is the resulting json;

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Lat","type":"number"},{"label":"Long","type":"number"},{"label":"Name","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":52.24655},{"v":-6.34384},{"v":"EUR6"}]},{"c":[{"v":52.24655},{"v":-6.34384},{"v":"EUR4"}]},{"c":[{"v":52.24655},{"v":-6.34384},{"v":"EUR2"}]},{"c":[{"v":52.64901},{"v":-8.57918},{"v":"EUR2"}]},{"c":[{"v":52.24655},{"v":-6.34384},{"v":"EUR3"}]}]}
```

This is the javascript file for the Google chart map;

```
// Load the Visualization API and the map package.
    google.load('visualization', {'packages': ['map'] });
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "demo_02.json",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
      var options = {
          //title: 'Location',
          showTooltip: true,
          showInfoWindow: true,
          enableScrollWheel: true,
          mapType: 'normal'
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('demo_02_div'));
      map.draw(data, options);
    }
```

And this is the html for testing purposes;

```
<html>
  <head>

    <!--Load for maps-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*************************************************&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--PHP-->
    <script type="text/javascript">$.ajax({url: "demo_02.php"})</script>

    <!--Javascript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo_02.js"></script>


  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="demo_02_div">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first**: recommend using `loader.js` to load the library, vs. `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['map']
});
```

---

**next**: `arrayToDataTable` is a *static* method (don't need the `new` keyword)

however, that method is used to load basic *array* data

to load *json* data, just create a `DataTable` directly

`var data = new google.visualization.DataTable`

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['map']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({"cols":[{"label":"Lat","type":"number"},{"label":"Long","type":"number"},{"label":"Name","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":52.24655},{"v":-6.34384},{"v":"EUR6"}]},{"c":[{"v":52.24655},{"v":-6.34384},{"v":"EUR4"}]},{"c":[{"v":52.24655},{"v":-6.34384},{"v":"EUR2"}]},{"c":[{"v":52.64901},{"v":-8.57918},{"v":"EUR2"}]},{"c":[{"v":52.24655},{"v":-6.34384},{"v":"EUR3"}]}]});
  var options = {
    showTooltip: true,
    showInfoWindow: true,
    enableScrollWheel: true,
    mapType: 'normal'
  };
  var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('demo_02_div'));
  map.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="demo_02_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you WhiteHat! That really helped me out, Your answer helped me get a better understanding of the methods and I will be make better use of Google Charts support from now on. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Samuel Liew, Félix Gagnon-Grenier, Ashish Nitin Patil, Aditya Vyas-Lakhan, EdChum. I thought I was clear in my question but looking back over it I could have phrased it better. Lesson learned for the future, thanks.

Comment: cheers! glad to help...